# Python 2.7 suddenly gone after using pip

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

After a fresh install of Python 3.7 and 2.7 I tried to use it. Displaying version working good with `py -2.7 -V` and the second after the 2.7 version drops from the launcher.

[image: Python 2.7 disappeared on Windows]

Installation folders:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27
```

I tried to reinstall all versions (without the PATH environment variable) and the issue came back. I checked the register, everything is Ok. I used official .exe/.msi packages to install Python.

Anyone has a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer myself: Avast decided to quarantine the .exe of Python 2.7! Damn it!